# Fresh/Deno Twind config file location

Tags: tailwind-css, preact

I am trying to add 
`backgroundImage: { 'split-white-black': "linear-gradient(to bottom, #111827 60% , white 40%);"  }`

to the tailwind config file but cannot see to find the file or where to put the code in the Fresh framework directory.

Thanks :)

Comment: Tailwind, or Twind? Fresh ships with support of Twind, which you can configure by passing your config to `setup()`.

Comment: Twind, so define a config then pass it to the setup() imported from twind

Comment: Is there a question here? It's just a config object. You can put it anywhere,, just have to import & consume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official fresh website is open source and simply puts it at the root of the project.

https://github.com/denoland/fresh/blob/main/www/twind.config.ts